# How can I use Trigonometry and Pi correctly in Java

Tags: java, math, trigonometry, pi

//Here is my method that I have created.

//I want my radius1 to equal "7.07" but once I use the method it gives me zero

```
public double getCircumscribedCircleRadius()
   {
       radius1 = 1 / 2 * 10 * 1 / Math.sin( Math.PI / 4);
       return radius1;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast you result in double :

```
 double radius1 = (double) 1 / 2 * 10 * 1 / Math.sin( Math.PI / 4);
```

> output : 7.0710678118654755

Comment: Actually what you are doing is casting the first `1` to double and thus starting the computation in double instead of integer arithmetic where `1/2` results in `0`. You could equally replace `(double) 1 / 2` with `0.5` or `(double) 1` with `1.0`.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize that fraction was the problem until you put a (double) in front of the expression to have it get the correct result. Thank you for explaining =)